# Возникает ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

Возникла ошибка при переходе с SQLlite на PostgresQl.

Выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Вот код:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['shop','магазин'])
async def __shop(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Магазин ролей",color=0x00d166)

    for row in cursor.execute(
        "SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            embed.add_field(
                name = f"Роль  ``{ctx.guild.get_role(row[0])}``",
                value = f"Стоимость роли: {row[1]} :leaves:",
                inline = False
            )

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Трейс ошибки полностью:

```
Ignoring exception in command __shop:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DirectoryStorm\Miku\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DirectoryStorm\Miku\bot\cogs\Statistics.py", line 134, in __shop
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = %s", [ctx.guild.id])
# NOTE:   защита от SQL Injections ---------------------> ^^
# передаем значения параметров в запрос ---------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

# цикл по возвращенным строкам результата запроса
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    ...
```